# Old, upvoted questions with upvoted answers in Review Queue

Tags: discussion

So the close review queue showed [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2030189/general-c-performance-improvement-tips) which is 8 years old, upvoted, and has upvoted answers...

If I strictly follow the rules, I would VTC, and that question will be closed, and probably deleted...

What does the community (and **especially C++ tag badge holders**) think?

Is there a case for locking questions like these rather than closing and eventually deleting them?

Comment: for full disclosure, I decided to leave open...maybe I am just bloody-minded

Comment: closing is easy, deleting is a lot harder. A question with so many votes will not likely be deleted.

Comment: for better or worse, it's now *On hold*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Upvoted closed questions won't get *probably deleted*.

Closing such a question is fine. It will prevent new answers from being added, not much else. Since the question is *way* too broad, it will likely mainly attract links to offsite resources, which we don't want, so not adding new answers is good. People will still be able to find and edit the question and answers, so no harm there. If the question should be deleted is an entirely different issue.

It does open up the possibility for users to delete the question, but the more upvotes something has, the more delete votes are required, and users casting delete votes will need to have at least 10K rep. It's unlikely the question will get *accidentally* deleted, and questions with more than 1 upvote will never get automatically deleted.

Comment: I would prefer to have the question locked by the Mods rather than closed... maybe that needs to be an option `Recommend locking to Mods`?

Comment: Why would you want it locked? Locking prevents edits, so dead links can no longer get fixed, and you can no longer vote. Locking is far more limiting than closing, and should mainly be used in the case of problems (destructive edits and such) imo. I think closed is a perfectly fine status for a question like this.

Comment: hmmm, yes you're right...